# Collapsing a range into a hidden area, but excluding a possible label at the start of range

Tags: ida

Suppose you have code like this (and you don't want to shell out the amount for the HexRays decompiler plugin):

```
loc_4BEEEF:                             ; CODE XREF: DriverEntry+28j
                push    50505050h       ; Tag
                push    1234h           ; NumberOfBytes
                push    ebx             ; PoolType
                call    ds:ExAllocatePoolWithTag
                cmp     eax, ebx
                jz      short loc_4BEEFF
```

Now for these cases I tend to write IDC scripts that collapse the `push`, `push`, `push`, `call` into a single hidden area.

However, since the hidden areas in IDA seem to be based on the address and the first `push` is a "named location", the indication that this is a label gets lost when I "name" my hidden area with descriptive pseudo-code, like this:

```
; eax := ExAllocatePoolWithTag(ebx, 1234h, 'PPPP')
                cmp     eax, ebx
                jz      short loc_4BEEFF
```

and if I can deduce the value of `ebx`, as would be possible here, I'd even convert that into:

```
; eax := ExAllocatePoolWithTag(NonpagedPool, 1234h, 'PPPP')
                cmp     eax, ebx
                jz      short loc_4BEEFF
```

Is there **any** way, short of starting my hidden area *after* the first `push`, that would allow me to hide the instructions and replace them with more descriptive pseudo-code, while at the same time *retaining* the label/name that coincides with the passing of the (last) argument?!

That is, my goal is to have it something like:

```
loc_4BEEEF:                             ; CODE XREF: DriverEntry+28j
; eax := ExAllocatePoolWithTag(NonpagedPool, 1234h, 'PPPP')
                cmp     eax, ebx
                jz      short loc_4BEEFF
```

(the comment behind the `loc_4BEEEF` label is *not* important to me, though)

Of course allocation is but one of the cases where this applies and where the first pushed (i.e. last) argument ends up at a named location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use *manual instructions*.

From https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/651.shtml:

> #### SetManualInsn
>
> ```
> // Specify instruction represenation manually.
> //      ea   - linear address
> //      insn - a string represenation of the operand
> // IDA will not check the specified instruction, it will simply display
> // it instead of the orginal representation.
>
> void   SetManualInsn   (long ea, string insn);
> ```

You can test it through the UI via `Edit → Other → Manual instruction...` or by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.

You would set the manual instruction for address `0x4BEEEF` to `eax := ExAllocatePoolWithTag(NonpagedPool, 1234h, 'PPPP')`. You could then put the remaining `push`es and `call` into a hidden area, or alternatively, set manual instructions for those `push` and `call` instructions with  (blank space) as the manual instruction value.